# How do add a menu with levels within page

Tags: menus

We've managed to add a menu into a page:

https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-wordpress-navigation-menu-in-posts-pages/

How though do you make it function like a normal menu that is in the header area? I.e. with showing only the 1st level. Then on click/hover action, the 2nd level, and 3rd level etc?

Perhaps even adding an icon next to each menu item to make clear it is to be clicked?

Answer (score 1):

All of this can be accomplished by styling your menu using CSS. Here is a basic example for styling a dropdown menu with CSS that you can use to start. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reply. While that does work, we are looking for a widget/plugin/simpler method to apply the menu to a post/page, without creating the files etc. Your example doesn't use the inherint WordPress menu system. We have the menu already created and displaying in the page. We only want to mimic the header menu function of dropdown menus appearing only on click of icon. Does that make sense?

Comment: The problem with using CSS only for inherent WordPress menu is that the different levels of sub menus have the same div "sub-menu". So would all collapse at same time. I'll try using custom CSS classes.

Comment: The problem is there is nothing in the standard CSS for WP menu that signifies 2nd, 3rd, 4th level etc.

Comment: Worked out how normal WP menu hides sub menus, done with opacity: 0; but that won't work for vertical menu in page, rather than horizontal menu in header. As the menus are all there, just hidden and then show on hover, which doesn't look great. They need to slide out etc. I think JS needed not just CSS.